# How exactly does Tomcat run out of CATALINA_HOME and CATALINA_BASE

Tags: tomcat6, tomcat

I'm having trouble finding documentation regarding this. After some googling I find that bin, conf,logs, temp, webapps, work are directories that should exist in `CATALINA_BASE`.

temp, logs, webapps, bin and work I don't have any trouble understanding.

bin I suppose is just another bin folder, if for some reason both `CATALINA_HOME` and `CATALINA_BASE` are in PATH, then scripts in both folders will be available for execution.

But how about conf? Will the content of `CATALINA_HOME/conf` be totally ignored if `CATALINA_BASE` is set? Suppose I only would need to customize only a few config files pr. `CATALINA_BASE`, would I still need to keep a complete set of config files in `CATALINA_BASE/conf`, or could the standard config files in `CATALINA_HOME/conf` be shared?

And ditto for `CATALINA_BASE/lib` ... would this work as a "global" lib folder pr. instance?

Answer (score 4):

You can find the answer in the Tomcat documentation:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/RUNNING.txt

> ## Advanced Configuration - Multiple Tomcat Instances
>
> In many circumstances, it is desirable to have a single copy of a
>   Tomcat binary distribution shared among multiple users on the same
>   server.  To make this possible, you can set the `$CATALINA_BASE`
>   environment variable to the directory that contains the files for your
>   'personal' Tomcat instance.
>
> When you use `$CATALINA_BASE`, Tomcat will calculate all relative
>   references for files in the following directories based on the value
>   of `$CATALINA_BASE` instead of `$CATALINA_HOME`:
>
> - bin  - Only setenv.sh (*nix), setenv.bat (windows) and tomcat-juli.jar
> - conf - Server configuration files (including server.xml)
> - logs - Log and output files
> - webapps - Automatically loaded web applications
> - work - Temporary working directories for web applications
> - temp - Directory used by the JVM for temporary files (java.io.tmpdir)
>
> Note that by default Tomcat will first try to load classes and JARs
>   from `$CATALINA_BASE/lib` and then `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`. You can place
>   instance specific JARs and classes (e.g. JDBC drivers) in
>   `$CATALINA_BASE/lib` whilst keeping the standard Tomcat JARs in
>   `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`.
>
> If you do not set `$CATALINA_BASE`, `$CATALINA_BASE` will default to the
>   same value as `$CATALINA_HOME`, which means that the same directory is
>   used for all relative path resolutions.